# how to group by product a list of objects and then count same products on same day

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

what I'm trying to do is grouping by product and ensure same product is schedule to be counted on same days always, the daysScheduled can not be more than product types
MILK,CHAIR,TABLE, TV = 4 product types and max scheduledDays would be 4

I have a list of products and I want to count same products on same days

```
int scheduledDays = 2;

IList<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products.Add(new Product("MILK", "123"));
products.Add(new Product("MILK", "123"));
products.Add(new Product("CHAIR", "456"));
products.Add(new Product("CHAIR", "456"));
products.Add(new Product("CHAIR", "456"));
products.Add(new Product("TABLE", "234"));
products.Add(new Product("TABLE", "234"));
products.Add(new Product("TV", "567"));
```

**EXPECTED**
if scheduledDays is 2, the products to be counted the first day will be, notice that scheduledDays values could be 1,2,3, etc and the list of product could have another items as well

```
      PRODUCTS TO BE COUNTED DAY 1                     PRODUCTS TO BE COUNTED DAY 2
products.Add(new Product("MILK", "123"));   |     products.Add(new Product("TABLE", "234"));
products.Add(new Product("MILK", "123"));   |     products.Add(new Product("TABLE", "234"));
products.Add(new Product("CHAIR", "456"));  |     products.Add(new Product("TV", "567"));
products.Add(new Product("CHAIR", "456"));  |
products.Add(new Product("CHAIR", "456"));  |
```

**EXPECTED**
if scheduledDays is 3, the products to be counted the first day will be, notice that scheduledDays values could be 1,2,3, etc and the list of product could have another items as well

```
      PRODUCTS TO BE COUNTED DAY 1                     PRODUCTS TO BE COUNTED DAY 3
products.Add(new Product("MILK", "123"));   |     products.Add(new Product("TABLE", "234"));
products.Add(new Product("MILK", "123"));   |     products.Add(new Product("TABLE", "234"));
                                            |     products.Add(new Product("TV", "567"));
      PRODUCTS TO BE COUNTED DAY 2      
products.Add(new Product("CHAIR", "456"));  |    
products.Add(new Product("CHAIR", "456"));  |
products.Add(new Product("CHAIR", "456"));  |
```

Ensure same product is scheduled to be counted on same day always, I was trying to use groupby something like this, but I do not know how to split with scheduledDays, I'm completely blocked, please help

```
int scheduledDays = 2;
var lists = products.GroupBy(x => x.Product);
foreach (var group in lists)
{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are in the right direction, you just need to run a loop.

The trick is to skip the last previous groups items and then take the `scheduledDays`  items.

```
foreach (var group in lists)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < scheduledDays; i++)
    {
        days.Add(group.Skip(i * scheduledDays).Take(scheduledDays).ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: what type is the "days" variable?

Comment: `List<List<Product>`

Comment: but "var group" has 4 groups and is going to iterate four times